# PHP: Function to group array of objects by value

Tags: php, unique

I am working with a multi-dimensional array. How can I remove duplicates by value? In the following array, [0], [2] and [5] have the same [ID]. Is there a function that will remove any duplicate arrays based on a particular value? In this case, I would like to remove array [2] and array [5], as they have the same [ID] as array [0].

Thank you for any information you may have.

```
        Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [d] => 2010-10-18 03:30:04
            [ID] => 9
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [d] => 2010-10-18 03:30:20
            [ID] => 4
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [d] => 2010-11-03 16:46:34
            [ID] => 9
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [d] => 2010-11-02 03:19:14
            [ID] => 1
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [d] => 2010-05-12 04:57:34
            [ID] => 2
        )    

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [d] => 2010-05-10 05:24:15
            [ID] => 9
        )

)
```

Comment: FYI, you keep using the term "key", but you area actually referring to a "value", not a "key".  The [0], [2], and [5] you mention are keys.  The [ID] is also a key.  The 9 that each of these ID's contains are all values.

Comment: thanks, i have modified the language of the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do it: (`$old_array` is your array, and `$new_array` will contain the new one, dupes removed, keyed by that ID)

```
$new_array = array();
foreach ($old_array as $item)
  if (!array_key_exists($item->ID, $new_array))
    $new_array[$item->ID] = $item;
```

(I haven't tested this, but it should work)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with [ouzo goodies](https://github.com/letsdrink/ouzo-goodies):

```
$result = FluentArray::from($array)->uniqueBy('ID')->toArray();
```

See http://ouzo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/utils/fluent_array.html#uniqueby

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easiest to loop through and construct a new array.  In the loop, use array_key_exists() to determine if the ID already exists in the new array, and if not, append an element.

Answer (score 0):

It is **not** a multidimensional array, it is an **array of objects**. You can just loop over it (this example changes the array in place):

```
$ids = array();

forach($array as $key=>$obj) {
    if(isset($ids[$obj->ID])) {//did we already encounter an object with this ID?
        unset($array[$key]); // if yes, delete this object
    }
    else {
        $ids[$obj->ID] = 1; // if not, add ID to processed IDs
    }
}
```

You can also create a new array and add the objects to the new array.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($array as $element) {
    foreach ($array as &$element2) {
        if ($element2->ID == $element->ID && $element2 != $element) {
            unset($element2);
        }
    }
}
```

Note the loop-by-reference in the second foreach.

Answer (score 0):

Check [indexed](https://github.com/ihor/Nspl#indexedarray-list-by-keeplast--true-transform--null) function from [Nspl](https://github.com/ihor/Nspl).

```
use function \nspl\op\propertyGetter;
use function \nspl\a\indexed;

$groupedById = indexed($objects, propertyGetter('id'));
```