# Array of objects top 5 unique values

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of arrays with two specific key/value pairs. What I am trying to do is to get the top 5 unique `cause` values decided by `qty`. Meaning that it would group the `cause` keys together by unique values, then total up the `qty` keys for each cause, and return the top 5 causes and the total qty for each cause.

Here is what the print_r(array_values($array)) prints out.

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [cause] => Other (please comment) [qty] => 0.417 ) 
[1] => Array ( [cause] => Chem Out FC-DryStrAddTow [qty] => 0.430 ) 
[2] => Array ( [cause] => Chem Out FC-DryStrAddTow [qty] => 0.430 ) 
[3] => Array ( [cause] => Chem Out FC-DryStrAddTow [qty] => 0.513 ) 
[4] => Array ( [cause] => Chem Out FC-DryStrAddTow [qty] => 0.513 ) 
[5] => Array ( [cause] => Chem Out FC-DryStrAddTow [qty] => 0.750 ) 
[6] => Array ( [cause] => Chem Out FC-DryStrAddTow [qty] => 0.750 ) 
[7] => Array ( [cause] => Slitter Cut/Saw-Poor Cut [qty] => 0.816 ) 
[8] => Array ( [cause] => Slitter Cut/Saw-Poor Cut [qty] => 0.816 ) 
[9] => Array ( [cause] => Slitter Cut/Saw-Poor Cut [qty] => 0.828 ) 
[10] => Array ( [cause] => Slitter Cut/Saw-Poor Cut [qty] => 0.828 ) 
[11] => Array ( [cause] => Slitter Cut/Saw-Poor Cut [qty] => 0.681 ) 
[12] => Array ( [cause] => Slitter Cut/Saw-Poor Cut [qty] => 0.681 ) 
[13] => Array ( [cause] => No Cause Selected [qty] => 0.918 ) 
[14] => Array ( [cause] => No Cause Selected [qty] => 0.918 ) 
[15] => Array ( [cause] => No Cause Selected [qty] => 0.926 ) 
[16] => Array ( [cause] => No Cause Selected [qty] => 0.937 ) 
[17] => Array ( [cause] => No Cause Selected [qty] => 0.809 ) 
[18] => Array ( [cause] => No Cause Selected [qty] => 0.809 ) 
[19] => Array ( [cause] => Slitter Cut/Saw-Poor Cut [qty] => 0.891 ) 
[20] => Array ( [cause] => Slitter Cut/Saw-Poor Cut [qty] => 0.891 ) 
[21] => Array ( [cause] => Slitter Cut/Saw-Poor Cut [qty] => 0.884 ) 
[22] => Array ( [cause] => Slitter Cut/Saw-Poor Cut [qty] => 0.884 ) )
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Please format that blob of output, it is practically unreadable.

Comment: It is a array with subarrays, not of objects

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96759/how-do-i-sort-a-multidimensional-array-in-php

Comment: i have tried several things from this site.[link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4329778)

Comment: `$ids = array();

forach($array as $key=>$obj) {
    if(isset($ids[$obj->ID])) {//did we already encounter an object with this ID?
        unset($array[$key]); // if yes, delete this object
    }
    else {
        $ids[$obj->ID] = 1; // if not, add ID to processed IDs
    }
}`

Comment: `foreach ($array as $element) {
    foreach ($array as &$element2) {
        if ($element2->ID == $element->ID && $element2 != $element) {
            unset($element2);
        }
    }
}`

Comment: @GarySenter: why don't you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

// Total up the quantities
$totals = array();
$tally  = array();
foreach ($datapoints as $entry) {
    if (!isset($totals[$entry['cause']]) {
        $totals[$entry['cause']] = 0;
        $tally[$entry['cause']]  = 0;
    }
    $totals[$entry['cause']] += $entry['qty'];
    $tally[$entry['cause']]++;
}

// Sort them, 'descending' or 'reverse', so the larger entries are first
arsort($totals, SORT_NUMERIC);

// Take the first 5 entries from the sorted list
$top = array_slice($totals, 0, 5);

// Do something with it.
foreach ($top as $cause => $totalQty) {
    echo $cause . ': ' . $totalQty . ' with ' . $tally[$cause] . ' events' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

If this data is coming from a database though, it would be better to use the database and SQL, with something like:

```
SELECT cause, SUM(qty) as totalQty, COUNT(qty) as tally
FROM data
GROUP BY cause
ORDER BY totalQty DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

Rather then load all the data and processing in php.

Comment: How can i get the total count for each of them? I need to display how many times each of them existed as well.

Comment: In php, you could create a tally hash in the loop that totals the quantities "$tally[$cause]++;" or if it is an option, in the SQL add 'COUNT(qty) as tally' to the select clause.

Comment: Is this right?`foreach ($qp_cause_array as $entry) {
if (!isset($qptotals[$entry['cause']])) {
 $qptotals[$entry['cause']] = 0;
}
$qptotals[$entry['cause']] += $entry['qty'];
$tally[$cause]++;
}`

Comment: Fairly close.  $cause isn't defined inside the foreach loop.  Edited my answer to include this additional feature.

Answer (score 1):

if using php 5.3+  you can use closures in your code and sort like (descending by qty)

```
usort($arary,function($a,$b){
    return $b['qty'] - $a['qty']
}
```

after this you can loop through the array and take the first 5 uniques.